# Commerce: Is there any way to give a discount for Product A if the costumer buy 3 Product B?

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce, ecommerce, plugin-craftcommerce3, discounts

In Craft Commerce 3, there is a Order Condition Formula that allow us to condition for the discount. So here is my Case.

- I have product A and Product B, so I will give a discount to Product A if the costumer buy 3 of Products B.

I tried to use this formula

```
order.lineItems|filter(v => (v.sku == 'SKU A' and qty >= 3) )
```

but the filter is not allowed in this formula, so is there any other way to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will need to uncomment this line to allow `|filter` used in condition formulas:

https://github.com/craftcms/commerce/blob/develop/src/services/Formulas.php#L198

If you do that manually yourself this formula works:

`order.lineItems|filter(v => (v.sku == 'BBB' and v.qty >= 3) )`

You were missing the `v.` in front of `qty`.

Look in the next version of commerce for the `|filter` being available.